# does there exist such numbers satisfying this limit condition?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Does there exist $a_n\ge 0$ and $b_n\ge 0$, $n\ge 1$, such that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \dfrac{\sum_{x>a_n} b_n}{x} =1$$?

Comment: What are you summing over?

Comment: @setholopolus those $b_n$ with $a_n <x$

Comment: So $a_n$ and $b_n$ are sequences? I still don't get the indexing in that case, because they aren't inherently connected. Indexing the sum using $n$ would make more sense.

Comment: @setholopolus yeah they are sequences, maybe $\sum_{\{n:a_n <x\} } b_n$ is better to understand

Comment: Much better!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, and if I have well understood the question, $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and  $b_n=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$ works.

Comment: you're right,thanks!